# SQL Finding Duplicate Values of Rows Where Another Field has a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL is rusty, so i need help, and i hope i don't get confusing with my explanation.

I need a statement to find all duplicate values of Field A, if at least one of those rows has a constant value on Field B

Field A  |  Field B 
dog          |  Canines 
dog           |  NULL 
dog           |  NULL

Because Field B is Canines, i want all rows that duplicate the Field A value. I need a select statement, but my intention is to change a value on Field C for duplicates, but i can probably figure that out afterwards.

Comment: What would the output be?  Just one row with dog | canines?

Comment: I am pretty much just looking for how to select them, so output isn't that important, as long as i have the data. I will be updating the table to change Field C from 0 to 1, for all duplicate values of fields A where one of them is the same as Field B, but does not contain the value of Field B

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want all rows, where the `FieldB` value is not uniformly NULL.

This gives you the list of `FieldA`s with that characteristic:

```
select FieldA
from t
group by FieldA
having count(FieldB) > 0;
```

If you actually want the rows with the `NULL` values, then:

```
select FieldA, FieldB
from (select t.*, count(FieldB) over (partition by FieldA) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 0;
```

To get all FieldA where *one* of them is canines:

```
select distinct FieldA
from t
where FieldB = 'canine';
```

To get all the rows, use this in a `where` clause:

```
select *
from t
where t.FieldA in (select distinct FieldA
                   from t
                   where FieldB = 'canine'
                  );
```

Comment: I need to select all rows where there is a duplicate of Field A, and at least one of the Field B's equal 'Canines'. There are loads of other Field B values that i want to ignore.. I only want duplicates that have a specific Field B value.

Comment: Something like:
SELECT FieldA
FROM t
WHERE FieldB = 'Canines'
AND (Find all dups of FieldA)

Answer (score 2):

Your help allowed me to find it.. Thank you all. What i was looking for was:

```
SELECT FieldA
FROM t
WHERE FieldB = 'Canines'
AND FieldA 
IN
(
    SELECT FieldA
    FROM t
    GROUP BY FieldA
    HAVING COUNT(FieldA) > 1
)
```

Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To get all rows where `count(fielda) > 1` and one of `fieldb` has the value `canine`

```
select t1.fielda
from mytab t1
join (select fielda, count(*) as dups
      from mytab
      group by fielda) t2 on t2.fielda = t1.fielda
where t1.fieldb = 'canine'
and t2.dups > 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ff02/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

If you want every row where there are duplicates, and where at least one item in Field B is not null, this will pull that:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE FieldA IN (SELECT DISTINCT FieldA
                 FROM Table
                 WHERE FieldB IS NOT NULL)
   AND FieldA IN (SELECT FieldA
                 FROM Table
                 GROUP BY FieldA
                 HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: Not looking for Field B to be NOT NULL. Looking for at least one of the items to have the value of 'Canines' in Field B

Comment: I think Goat_CO's query was intended to allow the user to not have to hard code "canine" and automatically pick up "feline" or "ursine" or whatever else may be there.  Sort  of a bigger picture thing.  I might be wrong.