# SQL Finding records with one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm a newbie on SQL hence my limitation on coding it. This question is similar to this previous questions: [SQL Finding Duplicate Values of Rows Where Another Field has a Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738862/sql-finding-duplicate-values-of-rows-where-another-field-has-a-value) and [Oracle/SQL - Finding records with one value excluding nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180957/oracle-sql-finding-records-with-one-value-excluding-nulls)

I need a statement to find all duplicate values of *PersonID*, if at least one or more of those rows has a value on *CodeID*. It will also find the *PersonID* even the *CodeID* is null but with no *PersonID* duplicate.

```
PersonID  CodeID
----------------
Alvin      2
Simon      4
Simon      null
Theodore   null
Dave       1
Ian        2
Ian        null
Clare      null
Gale       3
Gale       5
```

Desired Result:

```
PersonID  CodeID
----------------
Alvin      2
Simon      4
Theodore   null
Dave       1
Ian        2
Clare      null
Gale       3
Gale       5
```

Many Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could approach this without using an analytic function if those are not an option for you.

```
select PersonID, CodeID
from T
where CodeID is not null or PersonID in (
    select PersonID
    from T
    group by PersonID
    having min(CodeID) is null
)
```

Comment: I prefer this one - as you said, not much of analytical function. DENSE_RANK is not even in my SQL vocabulary yet. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `RANK`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40b820/1/0)

```
SELECT
    PersonID, CodeID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY CASE WHEN CodeID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM tbl
) t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: @shawnt00 It'll work is the `RANK` is based whether `CodeID` is `NULL` or not.

Comment: I just realized you were using `DENSE_RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`.